# TextView will disappear when I tried to setTextColor with Data binding

Tags: data-binding

TextView will disappear when I tried to setTextColor with Data binding. Does anyone know how to fix or workaround this issue? Thanks a lot.

```
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@{tickerModel.diffPriceColor}"
        android:text="@{tickerModel.mName}"/>
```

Comment: And I had tried to use BindingAdapter as below and the issue as same before.

Comment: Do you have a 0 alpha? E.g. 0x000000FF

Answer (score 0):

Using BindAdapter

```
@BindAdapter({"txtColor"})
public static void setTxtColor(View view, String color){
    ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor(color));
}
```

in your layout use following line instead of "android:textColor":

```
app:txtColor="@{tickerModel.diffPriceColor}"
```

Hope can help you solve your problem.